# Is it possible to use Azure Shared Access Signature outside of Azure?

Tags: python, django, azure, shared-access-signatures

Since Azures [Shared Access Signatures (SAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) is an open standard I want to use it in my Django application which has no links to Azure whatsoever. I basically want to create a piece of code that creates read permission for the next 24 hours on a specific url I'm serving. So I've watched some video's on SAS and I installed the python library for it (`pip install azure-storage-blob`).

I read over the [README here on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#azure-storage-blobs-client-library-for-python) but as far as I can see it always requires an Azure account. Is it also possible to use SAS in my own (Python) application? I imagine it to create the hashes based on a pre-defined secret key for. If this is possible, does anybody have any example code on how to create the url and how to validate it? Preferably in Python, but example code in other languages would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 1):

While the original blob storage sas generation code exists [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_shared/shared_access_signature.py), I rather find the below simplified code more useful for your general purpose (inspired by [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#python)). **Adjust as per your need**. Below is the client side sas generation logic (hmac sha256 digest) using a secret key. Use the similar logic at server side to re-generate signature extracting URL params (sr, sig, se) and compare the same (sig) with that passed from client side to match. Note the shared secret key both at client and server side is main driver here.

```py
import time
import urllib
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

def get_auth_token(url_base, resource, sas_name, sas_secret):
    """
    Returns an authorization token dictionary 
    for making calls to Event Hubs REST API.
    """
    uri = urllib.parse.quote_plus("https://{}.something.com/{}" \
                                  .format(url_base, resource))
    sas = sas_secret.encode('utf-8')
    expiry = str(int(time.time() + 10000))
    string_to_sign = (uri + '\n' + expiry).encode('utf-8')
    signed_hmac_sha256 = hmac.HMAC(sas, string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
    signature = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(signed_hmac_sha256.digest()))
    return  {"url_base": url_base,
             "resource": resource,
             "token":'SharedAccessSignature sr={}&sig={}&se={}&skn={}' \
                     .format(uri, signature, expiry, sas_name)
            }
```